# Vector.contains() or Hashtable.get() which is better

Tags: java

I have to put my string data in a collection and then querying only if exists. for example:

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
v.add("a");
v.add("b");
if(v.contains("a")){}

Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>()
ht.put("a");
ht.put("b");
if(ht.get("a") != null){}
```

which way is better or is there a better solution?

Edit: It is a big data and i am looking for fastest solution.

Comment: "better" in what way? faster? Less memory consumption? nicer implementation ;)?

Comment: Need more context... Where is the data coming from?

Comment: You probably should be using either `Vector` **or** `Hashtable`. They're both obsolete.

Comment: What are you comparing here? Vector is NOT a KEY VALUE pair of datastructure. You should compare List with Vector

Comment: You're comparing apples with oranges here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the `Hashtable` should be faster, because a `vector` has worst case runtime`O(n)`, because it runs through the vector and searches for the element. `Hashtables` have a faster access of because of their implementation of saving based on the Hashvalues (`O(1)`).

Answer (score 7):

Both are considered obsolete - if you only need to check existence you can use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). It has `add` and `contains` methods like Vector.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for what you want to achieve is using a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
mySet.add(myString);
if(mySet.contains(myString)) {
    // do some work
}
```